# "Apagar" Event Listener - Firebase

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, firebase, xamarin

Asi es como agrego un `EventListener` de Firestore:

```
...
database.Collection("CambiosVenta")
                    .AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

Pero hay situaciones en donde quisiera que dejara de escuchar dado que el cliente ya no necesitara mas esa información. Es posible remover/apagar el listener hasta que lo vuelva a necesitar?

Actualmente lo que hago es solo ocultar los resultados nuevos ya que (a como mencione) no quiero que el cliente vea mas de esos resultados, pero el listener sigue activo y me parece un desperdicio de lecturas.

Comment: la respuesta está en la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java_11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logre de la siguiente forma:

```
IListenerRegistration vListener;

vListener = database.Collection("Publicaciones")
                    .AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

Y para apagar el listener lo hice de esta forma:

```
vListener.Remove();
```